# Trying to grab the week input value from weekly calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Found this plugin for a weekly calendar:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Week-Picker-Bootstrap-4/

I am trying to retrieve the week value from an INPUT within a DIV id called "weekpicker1".

For the time being, I'm just trying to print it in the console.

I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var weekpicker = $("#weekpicker1").weekpicker();

    $(weekpicker).on('blur', function()
    {
        console.log('hello');
    });
</script>
```

The input doesn't have an ID.  I can't figure out how to access it.  As you can see, I tried to use the "blur" handler. "Click" doesn't work either.

What can I do to grab the value of the INPUT within the DIV called "weekpicker1"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact use case is documented on the [plugin's Github repository](https://github.com/trco/bootstrap-weekpicker#getweek).

```
$(function() {
    var weekpicker = $("#weekpicker1").weekpicker();

    console.log(weekpicker.getWeek());
    console.log(weekpicker.getYear());

    var inputField = weekpicker.find("input");
    inputField.datetimepicker().on("dp.change", function() {
        console.log(weekpicker.getWeek());
        console.log(weekpicker.getYear());
    })
});
```

Comment: Wow.  Not sure how you found that so quick, but it solved my problem.  Thank you, sir.